# Tracking user activity in Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-for-work

I'm using Google Apps for my company. Is it possible to track the users' activity on my domain? (Search history, activity log, email, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if your question was general or specific. If general, then by logging into your Google Apps administration screens at https://google.com/a/[yourdomain.com] and going to **Reports > Apps Usage Activity**, you can get reports that cover the following and more:

- apps usage activity
- login and admin activity
- weekly active users
- documents shared externally
- review active
- suspended and blocked users
- monitor storage usage
- keep track of security metrics
- view login activity

Answer (score 0):

The majority of this can be done from the [Admin console](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4589321).

Otherwise, you can use the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-admin).